# Version of twitter bootstrap used in twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem for my rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3 web app.
How do I know which version of twitter bootstrap the gem is using?
Is it the bootstrap 3 or the legacy bootstrap 2.3.2?

I tried looking at the readme on their github page but did not find much information

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [you are not the only one with the doubt](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/690), docs say nothing about it.

The master branch uses `v2.3.2`, but there's also a `bootstrap3` [branch](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3) you can use.

Comment: Thanks scumah. I will give the bs3 branch a try